# Visible Mass Distribution in a Galaxy

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, galaxies

Is there any known relationship between stellar density and distance from the galactic centre? I want to know how the visible matter is distributed in the galaxy, especially at the bulge.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167323/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80837/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169124/